# passing argument from shell script to hive script

Tags: bash, hadoop, hive

I've a concern which can be categorized in 2 ways:
My requirement is of passing argument from shell script to hive script. 
OR 
within one shell script I should include variable's value in hive statement.

I'll explain with an example for both:

1) Passing argument from shell script to hiveQL->

```
My test Hive QL:
select count(*) from demodb.demo_table limit ${hiveconf:num}
```

My test shell script:

```
cnt=1
sh -c 'hive -hiveconf num=$cnt -f countTable.hql'
```

So basically I want to include the value of 'cnt' in the HQL, which is not happening in this case. I get the error as:

```
FAILED: ParseException line 2:0 mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting Number near 'limit' in limit clause
```

I'm sure the error means that the variable's value isn't getting passed on.

2) Passing argument directly within the shell script->

```
cnt=1
hive -e 'select count(*) from demodb.demo_table limit $cnt'
```

In both the above cases, I couldn't pass the argument value. Any ideas??

*PS: I know the query seems absurd of including the 'limit' in count but I have rephrased the problem I actually have. The requirement remains intact of passing the argument.*

Any ideas, anyone?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you do echo in second case and see what you are getting: echo 'select count(*) from demodb.demo_table limit $cnt'

Comment: Using single-quotes suppresses expansion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set the variable this way:

```
#!/bin/bash
cnt=3
echo "Executing the hive query - starts"
hive -hiveconf num=$cnt -e ' set num; select * from demodb.demo_table limit ${hiveconf:num}'
echo "Executing the hive query - ends"
```

Comment: `num="$cnt"`, if you want to make the answer more generic (able to pass things that aren't just numbers and may contain whitespace, glob characters, etc).

Comment: Thanks sras, this is perfect. I never used multiple options for hive from command line. Totally agree with Charles; single quotes suppresses information.

Comment: to be more precise, we can use `hivevar` name space rather than `hiveconf` name space. However both will work for your query.

Answer (score 2):

This works, if put in a file named `hivetest.sh`, then invoked with `sh hivetest.sh`:

```
cnt=2
hive -e "select * from demodb.demo_table limit $cnt"
```

You are using single quotes instead of double.
Using double quotes for OPTION #1 also works fine.

Answer (score 1):

hadoop@osboxes:~$ export val=2;

hadoop@osboxes:~$ hive -e "select * from bms.bms1 where max_seq=$val";

or

```
vi test.sh
#########
export val=2
hive -e "select * from bms.bms1 where max_seq=$val";
#####################
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this
cnt=1

```
hive -hiveconf number=$cnt select * from demodb.demo_table limit ${hiveconf:number}
```